# Remove thumbnails numbers in WooCommerce single product gallery

Tags: css, wordpress, image, woocommerce, product

Bellow, you may see numbers on the left side of each small image:

[image]

How can these numbers be removed and place these images close to each other?

These numbers make the page very ugly. I tried to remove it but haven't found any solution.

Comment: paste html, it is an HTML, CSS issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This numbers will be removed just adding the following CSS rule to the `styles.css` file of your active child theme *(or active theme)*:

```
.single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-gallery ol > li {
    list-style: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Down voting a good answer without leaving a good reason is just really ugly!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes you are right, it seems some people don't know the answer but they think that they are so smart to down vote other people's answers by showing that it's not a correct.